# Unity dependency based warning: mscorlib, System

Tags: visual-studio, dependency-injection, unity-container

I get this when I add Unity to my project, and no longer get this once I remove it.  Tried package -reinstall..

I'm using .net 4.7 in VS 2017

No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
12>No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

Comment: I suspect that this has something to do with the fact nobody has made a commit to the [Unity repository](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) in nearly a year and a half and you are using .NET 4.7, which was [created very recently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.7). Simple solution - find a DI container that has support for new projects rather than using an [unsupported (dead) one](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues/73).

Comment: Unity is the simplest and easiest ioc to deal with.  Ill keep it and live with the warnings.  @NightOwl888